# What do you call the sounds of a crowd talking, moving, laughing, etc?

Tags: word-request

Like in video games, if you go into a town, there's the ambient sound of a large crowd playing in the background. What do you call such sounds? I completely forgot what it was called.

Comment: "Crowd noises"?

Comment: I personally like the aesthetic of 'din'

Comment: It's simply *background noise*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common word I know of is **hubbub.**

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hubbub

> **hubbub**
>
> noun
>
> 1. a loud, confused noise, as of many voices:
>
> *There was quite a hubbub in the auditorium after the announcement.*
>
> 2. tumult; uproar.

Comment: @JasonBassford, per the OP:  "Like in video games, if you go into a town, there's the ambient sound of a large crowd playing in the background."  In the context of the question, such a sound effect would not be quiet (no sound effect would be needed), nor would it be humming a tune (not typical behavior of a random group of people in a public place).  "Hubbub" may not be a perfect fit but it's a reasonable answer, and the OP did accept it.